# org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am upgrading my application from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4. In some of the queries I am returning empty string "" in select statement without any alias. 
This works fine with Hibernate 3. When I upgrade it to Hibernate 4, then I get the exception:
 org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query

If I give aliases to them then it works fine, but I have to change it across many places, which is tedious job. Please let me know if there is any other way to resolve it?
I know we should have unique aliases for all the select attributes, but in my case application is very vast, and can't change it manually